# How was the deep blue colour of these astronaut "jump suits" selected?

Tags: astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle

I've seen **most of the time** Astronauts and/or Cosmonauts wearing blue coloured clothes either on Earth or in the ISS. Is there any specific reason for the choice of this colour? I think it's to show that we are from the Blue Planet (Earth).

[image]

Image Source: [This Quora Answer](https://qr.ae/TWHEU2)

The Quora Answer linked above doesn't explain the reason for this choice.

Comment: I don't think the colour has a practical use. The jumpsuits might purely be for aesthetics or to associate a certain colour with a certain mission. All shuttle astronauts wore orange jumpsuits during launch and re-entry because it stands out against the surrounding environment if they were to be stranded. But I don't think they wear blue for a reason. Might as well ask, "why am I wearing a green t-shirt today?". The answer is because it's the first thing I found and it doesn't look bad :)

Comment: The orange suits weren't jumpsuits, they were pressure suits.  These blue flight suits are mostly worn when flying in the T-38s or for PR. They weren't worn in space at all, to my recollection.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, They were indeed worn in space and are currently worn during special events (post-launch, hatch closing, etc.). See [this](https://www.voanews.com/science-health/3-astronauts-safely-aboard-international-space-station) webpage.

Comment: @Intellex those aren't the same blue garments in the picture from the ISS. Those are Russian-supplied  garments.  Note the national emblems across the chest, not present in the NASA garments.

Comment: @Intellex they have a large national emblem on the chest that is not present in the NASA garments.  In the front row you see a Canadian maple leaf, a Russian colored stripes set, and a USA emblem of some sort. All this is missing from the standard flight suit.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, But see those in the 2nd row.

Comment: @Intellex see the white horizontal stripes in the 2nd row? not on the NASA flight suits.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, Sharp Eyes. Anyway my question remains the same. Why "Blue"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, As a retd. Human Space Flight Engineer, I hope you know the answer for this choice.

Answer (score 5):

In the ISS, they don't wear blue clothes only :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There seems to be a preferation of khaki pants, but there is one in light blue too.

Sorry, I found no information about the deep blue jump suits worn on Earth.

*Another orbit image added by Organic Module:*

(not even in the shuttle)

[image]

Comment: Fine :D ; Just include "most of the time" in my question.

Comment: Many thanks to Organic Marble for the very cool picture.

Comment: If you're that far above the clouds, sunglasses are entirely justified!

Comment: I found another [image](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/koch-meir-and-morgan_0.jpg)  with pants in black and dark blue, but I hesitate to add it.

Comment: @Uwe, Everything is ok. But can you tell why astronauts wear blue stuff **most of the time**-post-launch, hatch closing ceremony, events on Earth, etc.?

Comment: @Intellex branding most likely? Just like how SpaceX astronauts will likely wear spaceX suits and Roscosmos will wear Russian suits; NASA will wear blue tell-tale suits (honestly, probably, because the NASA symbol is 90% blue).

Comment: Agreed. Someone thought it was a snazzy looking color. In the pre-Challenger era they wore lighter blue outfits in space http://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/shared/npr/styles/x_large/nprshared/201310/157256035.jpg

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn, Maybe. But all astronauts/cosmonauts wear them. See [this](https://www.voanews.com/science-health/3-astronauts-safely-aboard-international-space-station).

Comment: @Intellex those are all branded for the ISS mission specifically, based on nationality (you can see the flags) and including emblems of the involved space agencies. But yeah, **as to why the blue was chosen** no idea. It would be odd for your astronauts not to at least minimally match for public pictures.